# How to implement my own login page instead of default Spring Security login page in Grails application?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

I have gone through some of the blogs in internet, but I am not able to find out how to do my own login page without Spring Security. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you need to do this tasks:

1. Create a login view inside views directory
2. create two gsp views names auth.gsp and denied.gsp
3. in this step you probably need to copy content from plugin auth.gsp view and denied.gsp if you are using grails spring security core plugin version 2.0-RC3 these views are located at target > work > plugins > spring-security-core-2.0-RC2 > grails-app > view > login, copy content and paste it in your app auth.gsp and denied.gsp views

You can check an example of views location and views content in this [repo](https://github.com/ilmoralito/petstore/tree/master/grails-app/views/login).

Answer (score 0):

To create a custom login page, create a view called auth.gsp in `grails-app/views/login/`. Make sure it passes the parameters `j_username` and `j_password` to the action `${postUrl}`. Here is the default auth.gsp view that comes with Spring Security 1.x:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name='layout' content='main'/>
    <title><g:message code="springSecurity.login.title"/></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${resource(dir: 'css', file: 'auth.css')}" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id='login'>
    <div class='inner'>
        <div class='fheader'><g:message code="springSecurity.login.header"/></div>

        <g:if test='${flash.message}'>
            <div class='login_message'>${flash.message}</div>
        </g:if>

        <form action='${postUrl}' method='POST' id='loginForm' class='cssform pure-form pure-form-aligned' autocomplete='off'>
            <p>
                <label for='username'><g:message code="springSecurity.login.username.label"/>:</label>
                <input type='text' class='text_' name='j_username' id='username'/>
            </p>

            <p>
                <label for='password'><g:message code="springSecurity.login.password.label"/>:</label>
                <input type='password' class='text_' name='j_password' id='password'/>
            </p>

            <p>
                <input type='submit' id="submit" class="btn" value='${message(code: "springSecurity.login.button")}'/>
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    <!--
    (function() {
        document.forms['loginForm'].elements['j_username'].focus();
    })();
    // -->
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would copy that into your auth.gsp view and change it from there.

Comment: Is there a new way of doing this in Grails 3.x?

Answer (score 0):

This can be annoying sometimes.
So if am getting you right you want to change the look and feel of the login spring security offer right?

Do this after you are done with your UI design( CSS, HTML and others).

Now change the input name and compare it to `auth.gsp`, thus from Spring security.

You can hold `ctrl+shift+N` on the keyboard and type `auth.gsp` for you to check.

Compare it to yours and change where possible.

In your UrlMAppings.groovy do this editing

`"/"(view:"/Your login page")`

`"/login/auth"(view:"/Your login page")`

Now restart your service and thats all.

If the issue persist you can post the error here so we can see what to do to help.

Note this is for Grails 3.x